# Element is not identifed in the second test method

Tags: selenium-webdriver, page-factory

I have a strange behavior : I created Test Class with 2 Test Methods as below.

When I call `AddLimitedBuyOrderwithRandom` in the first method it works fine without any exception, but if I call `AddLimitedBuyOrderwithRandom` from the second method I get a `NoSuchElement` exception.

This is the code for the test class:

```java
public class TestLoginPage extends TestBase {
    public HomePage homeobject;
    public NewOrdersLoginPage OrderLoginObject;
    public OrderMgmtPage OrdersMgmentObject;

    @Test
    public void SuccessLogin() throws InterruptedException
    {
        homeobject = new HomePage(driver);
        homeobject.OpenOrdersPage();
        OrderLoginObject = new NewOrdersLoginPage(driver);
        OrderLoginObject.userLogin("140", "12345");
        OrdersMgmentObject = new OrderMgmtPage(driver);
        OrdersMgmentObject.AddLimitedBuyOrderwithRandom("10");
    }

    @Test(enabled= true)
    public void AddLimitOrderTest() throws InterruptedException
    {
        OrdersMgmentObject = new OrderMgmtPage(driver);
        OrdersMgmentObject.AddLimitedBuyOrderwithRandom("10");
    }   
}
```

and this is the code for `AddLimitedBuyOrderwithRandom`:

```java
public void AddLimitedBuyOrderwithRandom(String SharesCount) throws InterruptedException
{  
    clickButton(NewOrderLink);
    clickButton(BuyTypeRadio);
    selectDropdownByValue( companyList, "Company");
    typeText(ShareNoTxt, SharesCount);
    selectDropdownByValue(  OrderTypeList, "2");
    selectDropdownByValue( OrderValidityList, "0");
    double Pricerandom = getRandomNumberInRange(ReturnShareLimitDown(),ReturnShareLimitUp());
    typeText(SharePriceTxt,Double.toString(Pricerandom));
    clickButton(SubmitOrderBtn);    
}
```

(Added from comments on answers)
My base class is:

```java
public class TestBase 
{ 
    public static WebDriver driver ; 
    public static String downloadPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\Downloads"; 
    public String BaseURL = "URL"; 

    @BeforeSuite 
    @Parameters({"browser"}) 
    public void startDriver(@Optional ("chrome") String browserType) 
    { 
        if (browserType.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome") ) 
        { 
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/drivers/chromedriver.exe"); 
            driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
        } 
    } 
    
    driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
    driver.navigate().to(BaseURL); 
}
```

Comment: In your first test, you log on before going to the order management page. In the second test, you don't - is it possible that not being logged in is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Many things are hidden on the code. It can be anything on your code or on the application logic.

But most likely is that you have just performed login once. When you open the browser on the second test, Selenium cleans everything.

You would have to login again or save some cookie, using a @BeforeSuite method.

Comment: I Already use @BeforeSuit : how to save Cookies

Answer (score 0):

Try to add wait before interacting with your element with waitForVisible.

E.g:

```
 NewOrderLink.waitForVisible(1000);
 clickButton(NewOrderLink);
```

Because on your first method, you have prior steps. Unlike in second step that you call it right away.